# Play Framework 2 Java Optional authentication

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have been playing around with authentication. I want to be able to have some extra functions on certain pages available for those who log in. The problem is that if I don't use the `@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)` annotation for the controller class I cannot get the username from the session so I cannot check if the user is logged in or not.

How should I go about this? Should I make sure all pages are authenticated and then have some sort of a guest login that automatically gets used for those other sessions or is there a way to check if the user is logged in even on a class without the `@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)` annotation.

It would be great if someone could point me in the right direction, if there is a tutorial available that does this or just some guidance.

Comment: is your problem that you have to check some function for session(for actions after user login) and ignore some function(for action before user is log in)?

Comment: yeah, I want to be able to have all un-authorized users see the page and list items etc but not be able to post a comment on the page.

Comment: so what is the problem you can use `@Security` at functional level rather than class level or you have `@With` also.

Answer (score 0):

You should do two things:

1. Prevent unauthenticated users from viewing the functionality in your template:

   ```
   @if(session().containsKey(Secured.SESSION_AUTH_KEY)) { /* Your comment form */ }
   ```
2. Prevent unauthenticated users from accessing your action:

   ```
   @Security.Authenticated(Secured.class)
   public static Result submitComment() {
       ...
   }
   ```

With:

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator {

    public static final String SESSION_AUTH_KEY = "email";

    public String getUsername(Http.Context context) {
        return context.session().get(SESSION_AUTH_KEY);
    }

    public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context context) {
        ...
    }
}
```